# Как сделать ссылку-статью Вконтакте?

Tags: vkontakte-api, вконтакте, статьи

Отправляю другу ссылку, и вижу вот этот значёк.(выделил красным)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
При нажатии открывает сайт в виде статьи Вк.
Как реализовать такое?

Answer (score 1):

Эта технология называется [AMP](https://amp.dev/ru/) (Accelerated Mobile Pages). VK [анонисровала](https://vk.com/blog/amp) такую поддержку в конце 2017 года. И, на вопрос *"Как реализовать такое"*, есть [гайд](https://amp.dev/ru/documentation/guides-and-tutorials/start/create/) на сайте документации.